# Compiling MonoDevelop from source error

Tags: mono, monodevelop

After a long night of compiling... allot of dependencies from source, I get the following error when trying to compile MonoDevelop under CentOS 5:

```
/opt/mono/bin/gmcs -debug -codepage:utf8 -win32icon:../../../theme-icons/Windows/monodevelop.ico -out:../../../build/bin/MonoDevelop.exe -r:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib/mono/mono-addins/Mono.Addins.dll   -r:../../../build/bin/MonoDevelop.Core.dll -r:../../../build/bin/MonoDevelop.Ide.dll  ./AssemblyInfo.cs ./MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs 
./MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs(22,49): error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.get_AddinSetupService'.
./MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs(22,49): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

any ideas?

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved, I have come across the same problem?

Comment: I never did solve it actually, because of the simple fact that CentOS Repos are outdated always... So your next best option is to compile everything from source - which in this was was actually EVERYTHING. Then you reboot and everything goes to hell with dependencies, things stopped working because you updated something... etc.

So now I'm a happy arch linux user, it's the most up-to-date linux distro I've ever seen. The installation is a little rough, but when you get there, it's beautifull. I just did "pacman -S monodevelop" and in 20 seconds it was installed and ready to use.